# gitlab-CI Efficiently fetching dependent git repos for CI jobs

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to set up a CI job that require dependent repositories to be placed along side the repository for which I'm enabling CI. By dependent, I mean that my main repo needs the code in the dependent repo but there is no build or test dependency between the two repos

I find a way to clone a dependent repository using this command in the job's script

`git clone https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.mycompany.com/path_to_my/dependent_repo.git`

The problem is that the repo is fresh cloned every time the job runs which takes way too long as the dependent repo is quite large.

Is there a way to "fetch" a dependent repo as efficiently as GitLab CI fetches its own repo (against which CI will run), basically performing a pull instead of a clone?

Should I use cache?

Answer (score 0):

If you have one main repo that depend on a few other repos, I would add these as submodules. This makes it easier to handle in GitLab, and your colleagues can easily find the correct versions they need to clone for these repos. If you have some specific need to not have these as submodules, then I understand!

In GitLab, there are a few different ways of handling this. The most simple one is to use the `GIT_STRATEGY`variable:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#git-strategy

You can set it to `fetch` like this:

```
my_job:
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: fetch
  script:
    - echo test
```

GitLab will then try to reuse an existing working directory instead of always cloning a new one.

I had a case myself when I used a flag for git clone called `--reference`:

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---reference-if-ableltrepositorygt

It has some very strange special cases that you have to think about. What the flag does is that git uses a local copy of a repository and copies objects from that one, instead of always copying from the network. This can greatly speed up cloning operations in some cases.

In addition to these suggestions, GitLab has a page with their suggestions to handle large repositories:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/large_repositories/